# Generic Parameter 'Key' could not be inferred Swift 2

Tags: swift2, ios9, xcode7

I am beginner in swift 2 and I not find the problem. the error is in this line:

```
let jsonDictionary try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData = (data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! Dictionary
```

```
func searchItunesFor(searchTerm: String) {
    let itunesSearchTerm = searchTerm.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil)
    let escapedSearchTerm = itunesSearchTerm.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let urlPath: String = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=\(escapedSearchTerm)&media=software"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {(data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        do {
            if let ipString = NSString(data:data!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding){
                let jsonDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! Dictionary

                let results: NSArray = jsonDictionary["results"] as NSArray
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.tableData = results
                    self.appsTableView?.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }catch{
            print("Bad ")
        }
    }).resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let jsonDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer so other users have a greater benefit from it?

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could help some one even though it's a bit late:

The issue here is that you are trying to cast a `JsonObject` to a `Dictionary` instead of a `NSDictionary`.

So you only need to replace `Dictionary` with `NSDictionary` in your code. That should take care of the error.

**Swift 2**

```
let jsonDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
```

**Swift 3**

```
let jsonDictionary = try JSONSerialization.JSONObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

What's working for me in Swift 3 is to define the dictionary key value types.

```
if let jsonDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary<String, String>{
    // something happens here
}
```

Notice the `NSDictionary<String, String>` at the end of that line.

This is if your object looks like this, of course:

```
{
    "someProp" : "some value",
    "someOtherProp" : "some other value"
}
```

If you don't know the value you're getting and it could be Any object use `NSDictionary<String, Any>`